# How do I improve teamcity build performance?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have the following steps for my project:

1. build
2. unit tests
3. test coverage
4. duplicates finder
5. fx cop

Is there any way to make TeamCity execute 2-5 steps in parallel? Can I use several build agents for that?

Comment: Do you need to run fxcop and duplicates finder with every build?  I only do that nightly. The problem with splitting them into different configurations is that you can have successful completions of one and not the other. So if your dev use pretested commits they may sometimes succeed when they shouldn't. Id rather build smaller units by csproj or groups of.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden, yep, I came to the same idea: run fxcop and duplicates at nightly build

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have at least four build agents, you can do the following:

1. Under `MyProject`, define 5 build configurations (`Build`, `Unit Tests`, etc).
2. Edit build configurations 2-5, and define a new `Trigger` in `Build Triggering` (Choose `Finish Build Trigger`, and set it to run after a successful run of `Build`.
3. Edit build configurations 2-5, and define a new `Artifact dependency` in `Dependencies` (Choose `Add new artifact dependency`, and choose the output of your `Build` configuration.

As long as you have agents available, the build configurations will run after a successful `Build`, each on its own agent.

On a side note, without knowing your specific project, i'd recommend doing that only if the whole process takes a really long time (lets say more than ~15 minutes), and you can spare those machines (virtual or not).