# Build (CI) server for embedded softtware

Tags: build, embedded, continuous-integration, build-automation

I would like to ask about your experience with build server for embedded systems. What are you using (if any), and what are good and bad sides.

We are developing mainly for microcontrollers without operating system.

At this moment I'm trying to use Jenkins and my build is running. But I have some problem with projects structure. When I want all plugins working, than I need flat job structure. But we have few projects that are developed in parallel, and then job view start to be messy.
I've tried folders, but than some plugins stopped working.

I would like to build a pipeline, that is running sequential, but have parallel jobs inside. eg. Commit stage have: compile, lint check, style check, unit tests. all of them can run in parallel and when all are successful next stage is executed.

What I need from Build server at this moment:

- build pipeline support
- user authorization based on LDAP
- parallel job execution
- hierarchical projects (projects/configurations groups)
- reports from xUnit, Lint, Compiler warnings, Robot framework.
- slave/agents support, tags for slave
- privileges based on ldap groups
- privileges per group/project

I'm opened for any suggestions, open source and commercial.
I was looking at Bamboo on videos look very nice but I didn't try it yet.

We have two development teams, that are developing different projects. It could be nice to have projects grouped for teams and privileges for group. Members of one group shouldn't modify builds of other. But it is more "nice to have" than "must have".

**TeamCity**

I tried to use TeamCity. Building build pipeline is easier than in Jenkins, just click add Step.

One thing that I found difficult is making steps in parallel in one configuration. For example after commit I would like to run in parallel Lint, Unit tests, Compile to save some time. I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970603/how-do-i-improve-teamcity-build-performance), but it make pipeline harder to view and maintain.

TeamCity support multiple configuration in projects which solve problem with jobs grouping. I didn't found option to group projects.

Answer (score 4):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is a free, Java-based CI server from JetBrains.  We've been using it very successfully (for very different kinds of projects) and I would unreservedly recommend it to you.  To each of your requirements:

- Build pipelines are configured as a series of steps within a build configuration.  A project can have an arbitrary number of configurations, which in turn can have an arbitrary number of steps.
- LDAP integration is fully supported.
- Build pipelines can be executed in parallel.  TeamCity delegates work to Build Agents, which are typically distinct servers that have all the necessary tools (frameworks, etc.) to perform the steps of a build configuration.  The free version of TeamCity comes with licenses for three agents, so you could have up to three builds running in parallel.  Additional agents can be licensed for a nominal fee.
- By 'hierarchical projects' I understand you to mean that the completion of one build pipeline will automatically trigger the start of a subsequent pipeline.  This is supported, and build/version numbers can be passed between the stages for consistency.
- XUnit has first-class support.  Lint/compiler reports can be saved as 'artifacts' of the build for easy review later.  Essentially, a lot of frameworks have built-in support in TeamCity, and for everything else you can execute arbitrary shell commands, the output of which can be saved as artifacts or used in subsequent build steps.
- Slave/agent support is central to the TeamCity model, as noted above.

All of this is highly configurable and customizable.  We've been able to do a lot of diverse, complex things with TeamCity, and it has been totally solid and stable for us.  And it looks good, too -- the server dashboard arranges information in an easily-understood way.

Comment: I will try to use TeamCity. From your description looks very interesting. By 'hierarchical projects' I was thinking more about grouping jobs, that I don't have all jobs on 'start page'. But it is based on Jenkins experience, and as I see in TeamCity it is different philosophy to make pipeline. I need to try. I'll update my question when I'll have experience with TeamCity.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for Atlassian so I'm a bit biased.

Configuring your build pipeline in Bamboo is pretty easy to do. Bamboo operates based on a Plan →  Stage →  Job structure, listed from higher to lower order. Check out the [Bamboo Plan Structure](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/289276853/BambooPlanAnatomy.png?version=1&modificationDate=1347425230605&api=v2).

Every Project in Bamboo holds a collection of Plans. Plans are comprised of one or more Stages. Stages run sequentially and are comprised of one or more Jobs. Jobs run in parallel and are comprised of one or more Tasks (tasks run sequentially, but can be placed in separate Jobs so that they run in parallel and speed up build time). Agents in Bamboo are machines or services that perform your build steps. An entire Job will execute on a single Agent. You can read more about Agents [here](http://quickstart.atlassian.com/download/bamboo/get-started/agents/). As for slave tags, the ability to make certain agents exclusively tied to certain builds or projects is on the short-list for new features.

To answer your other points:

- user authorization based on LDAP/privileges based on ldap groups/project: You can connect to an external LDAP server to manage users and permissions. Bamboo has a groups feature or if your team is using JIRA you can take advantage of JIRA groups to set up global permissions, plan permissions, and also indicate which users will receive notifications on a plan’s build results. Global permissions control who has access to build plans and the Bamboo server whereas Plan permissions control who can perform specific operations on a Plan and its Jobs.
- hierarchical projects (projects/configurations groups): Bamboo does support parent & child plan structure. There are several ways you can set up triggering for builds. One of them is to base triggers on other builds, that is, Plan builds are triggered by preceding successful builds of other plans or if other specified plans are building successfully. Example: If Plan A builds successfully it will automatically trigger builds of Plans B & C.
- reports from xUnit, Lint, Compiler warnings, Robot framework: Bamboo can run any build process that can be started from a command line. Support includes Maven/Maven2, Ant, make, MSBuild, NAnt, Grails, devenv.exe, and any xUnix-compiant framework (JUnit, Selenium, JWebUnit, NUnit, PHPUnit, etc...).

Comment: Thank you for information. Plans (sequential stages, parallel jobs) look better than chaining jobs in jenkins or configuration in Teamcity. I think I must finally install bamboo trial and play with it. I have one question about bamboo trial, how many agents I can run with trial license?

Comment: Happy to help. You can run 25 agents with the trial license. Should be enough to get you going.